# Application of splitting a photon into two

Tags: photons, quantum-information, quantum-optics, applied-physics, non-linear-optics

As you know, there are processes through which a photon is split into two photons, each with half energy. There are possibly processes where a photon is split into two ones with different energies.

Are there any applications for these processes or are they just cases of theoretical interest?

Answer (score 1):

Great question! There are indeed important applications for these types of processes, and that typically revolves around the fact that resulting pairs of photons are typically entangled.

For example, certain nonlinear processes can produce pairs of photons that are entangled in their polarization. With such pairs, there are already many interesting things that can be done - such as quantum teleportation!

From my view, an even more useful application is using entangled photons pairs to entangle atoms - ie., by mapping the state of each photon onto a different atom. This is an active subject of modern research. Being able to create 'on-demand' entanglement between atoms enables many amazing ideas in quantum information related to, for example, quantum communication.

Comment: But you are not splitting a photon in two!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A high frequency photon is annihilated and replaced by an entangled pair of low frequency photons. What exactly do you mean by 'splitting'?

Comment: Thank you Harry, and what is the last process you mentioned called?

Comment: I think it has to create something else first

Comment: Hi N.S. Are you asking about the name of the process of mapping photon entanglement onto atomic entanglement? One name for this would be 'remote entanglement'.